# how do i get the dimensions of the visible swf in AS 3.0

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

my movie is 500 by 200 px. However i am loading display object much larger than that and have just a portion of them show. How do i programatically get the visible dimesions? root.stage.width gives me the extended value.

for the sake of good programing practices i dont want to hardcore the values.

Comment: Yes, it's best to avoid hardcore values ;P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see [Stage::stageWidth](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Stage.html#stageWidth) and [Stage::stageHeight](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Stage.html#stageHeight).

Comment: thanks man, i feel stupid now for now reading the docs carefully enough

Comment: @vasion: don't. it's not super-obvious and one can well expect `width` and `height` to work just the way you did. it's not a mistake I haven't done as well. ;)